# angular: strange behavior with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I stumbled across a strange problem with ng-options. Consider a simple select:

```
<select ng-model="x" ng-options="n for n in [1,2,3]"></select>
```

where the model value gets assigned in the controller:

```
$scope.x = 3;
```

This works fine; the select element shows 3. However, if the assignment is *delayed*,

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.x = 3 }, 50);
```

The select shows up blank. But *only* if the model value is the last option in the list! In other words, this works fine:

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.x = 2 }, 50);
```

Then the select element shows 2. Same deal with 1. But 3 shows up blank.

What the?

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3GbZhRSTY8JUcVMOqG4B?p=preview) that demonstrates.

It's a problem that shows up with angular 1.2.26. Earlier versions are okay (you can see this for yourself by changing the angular version used by the plunk).

But my project has all kinds of dependencies and bower keeps pushing my angular to 1.2.29. Anybody got any idea how I might work around this issue?

Comment: Interesting. Seems to be a bug in 1.2.26 / 1.2.28.  If you switch to 1.3, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and eventually solved it by telling css not to display these options:

```
option[value^=\?]{
    display: none;
}
```

This has the effect of telling CSS not to display any option with a value attribute value starting with "?" (Note that the question mark must be escaped.)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in version 1.2.26 / 1.2.28, but works for 1.3.*.

I've submitted this as an issue to Angular:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10718

To work around this issue, initialize the scope variables in your ngController (outside of $timeout):

```
function ctrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.p_immediate = 3;
    $scope.s_immediate = "third";
    $scope.p_delayed = 0;
    $scope.s_delayed = "first";
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.p_delayed = 3;
        $scope.p_not_last = 2;
        $scope.s_delayed = "third";
        $scope.s_not_last = "second";
    }, 50);
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bp7kXZPD4SqECME7JZPE?p=preview)